# SVG Animation Jumping

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm beginning to just learn some SVG (and javascript, I suppose), and I'm having a hard time understanding why this is not flowing smoothly. The 0 moves a small amount (presumably "1" horizontally on the x axis), but than begins to leap in great bounds. Is this because the browser I am using (Chrome) is refreshing/redrawing at a much longer pace? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <svg width="100%" height="100%"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    onload="startup(evt)">
<script>
function startup(evt){
    svgDoc=evt.target.ownerDocument;
    setInterval(function(){
    e=svgDoc.getElementById("zero");
    var x = e.getAttribute("x");
    e.setAttribute("x",x+1);
    },1000);
}
</script>   
<defs>
    <text id="zero">0</text>
</defs>
<use x="40" y="20" xlink:href="#zero"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you're working with numbers and not strings:

```
var x = +(e.getAttribute("x"));
e.setAttribute("x",x+1);
```

JavaScript *prefers* string "addition" to numeric, so when "x" is a string, `x+1` means "add the character '1' to the end of the string x". By forcing the return value from `.getAttribute()` to numeric via the unary "+" operator, you avoid that problem.

(There are various ways to force a string to be converted to a number. Pick your favorite :-)